# Selenium will not show javascript loaded table in webpage with Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following webpage: https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/
(I have gained permission from the website)

The problem is that the "Monthly Breakdown" table seems to be loaded by Javascript, and BeautifulSoup does not work. When using Selenium to open the webpage, it says that to see the table "You must have Javascript enabled.", which should be enabled when using Selenium. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.maximize_window()

url = "https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/"
browser.get(url)
```

Any ways to solve this problem?

How the page should look:
[image]

How it looks on Selenium:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if you no longer get that error message:

```
options.add_argument("javascript.enabled", True)
```

You may also need to look into "waits" [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to make sure the async operation on the webpage has time to load.

Comment: It returns the following: TypeError: add_argument() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: OK, it doesn't like that True. You could try "javascript.enabled=true" but now I'm throwing out random solutions.

Before we get into this, have you thought about just grabbing the graph directly?

https://steamdb.info/api/GetGraph/?type=concurrent_week&appid=730

edit: if they've given you permission, they may have allowed this sort of crawling, which they typically disallow (via e.g., whitelisted ip, token).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

To enable or disable javascript :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()

#value 1 enables it , if you set to 2 it disables it     
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 1})

driver =webdriver.Chrome(r".\chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)


driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

**THis wont solve your issue**

you can check if the javascript is enabled by typing below in your address bar:

```
 chrome://settings/content/javascript?search=javascript
```

you can see that even if its enabled the website won't load properly.

it seems they have enabled security to avoid using selenium in thier website

**Previous answer:**

There is no command line argument called --enable-javascript chromium project try the above javascript-harmony flag instead.

below are the full list of supported chrome flags:

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#login-profile

please add screenshots and other information if more help is needed

Comment: Tried, but not loading tables on the webpage either

Comment: add screen shot and html of what you are trying to do , how you know its javascript issue ?

Comment: @user888905050219 added to the answer , it seems the website have security enabled to avoid use of bots in thier website

Comment: Strange, since they said crawling and scraping is possible with permission

Comment: @user888905050219 you can click the compare chart button in the browser opened , you can see chart loads successfuly. Talk to developer why its nt able to load on index page

Comment: @user888905050219 could you accept the answer if it helped